# Android: Not able to Run ffmpeg-1.0.1 and above

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I'm able to compile ffmpeg-0.8.14 and its creating the library file. If I compile ffmpeg-1.0.1 and above it is showing the following error.

**Error:**

> modifying Makefiles...   generating av.mk in ffmpeg...   start
>   ndk-building...   /android-ndk-r7b/build/core/build-binary.mk:41: ***
>   target file `clean' has both : and :: entries.  Stop.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: maybe you should try using github, searching on 'android-ffmpeg' and just use one of the projects out there. they all compile fine. u can look for one using a recent release of ffmpeg

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Its working upto FFmpeg-0.11.3 and its not working FFmpeg-1.0.1 and above.